# Making ArrayList.containsAll run faster

Tags: java, performance

Whenever using `ArrayList`, the method `containsAll(collection)` runs in time \$\mathcal{O}(mn)\$, where \$n\$ is the size of `ArrayList` and \$m\$ is the length of `collection`. However, it relies only on `equals(Object)`-method.

I have this subclass of `ArrayList` that does the same in time \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$, but relies on `hashCode()` as well.

My main question, should I do this optimization at expense of adding more requirements?

**MyArrayList.java**:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * This class provides a faster {@link #containsAll(java.util.Collection) } 
 * method.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6
 * @param <E> the actual element type.
 */
public class MyArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {

    /**
     * Returns {@code true} if this list contains all elements in {@code coll}
     * and {@code false} otherwise.
     * 
     * @param  coll the collection to check for inclusion in this list.
     * @return {@code true} if this list contains all elements in 
     *         {@code coll}:
     */
    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> coll) {
        Set<?> set = new HashSet<>(coll);

        for (E element : this) {
            if (set.contains(element)) {
                set.remove(element);

                if (set.isEmpty()) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        List<Integer> jdkList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> myList  = new MyArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
            jdkList.add(i);
            myList.add(i);
        }

        Random rnd = new Random();
        Collection<Integer> coll = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
            coll.add(rnd.nextInt(myList.size()));
        }

        // Uncomment for failing test.
        //coll.add(-1);

        long ta = System.currentTimeMillis();

        boolean result = jdkList.containsAll(coll);

        long tb = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("ArrayList.containsAll() in " + (tb - ta) + " ms. " +
                           "Result: " + result);

        ta = System.currentTimeMillis();

        result = myList.containsAll(coll);

        tb = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("MyArrayList.containsAll() in " + (tb - ta) + 
                           " ms. Result: " + result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Java benchmarking is tricky. You should read this before you make any conclusions based on your results: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Comment: I think when you test algorithms with different complexity O(mn) vs O(n) vs O(m), it usually still gives meaningful results as the performance difference can be an order of magnitude.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Relying on `.hashCode()` may or may not be faster and may or may not produce the same results as relying on `.equals()`.

Do you already see where this is going? The problem begins when you stop obeying the contract of the interface you implement. I'll quote the [javadoc for `contains` here:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains(java.lang.Object))

> Returns true if this collection contains the specified element. More
>   formally, returns `true` if and only if this collection contains at
>   least one element `e` such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`.

This is the formal definition for contains that also applies to containsAll.

Now considering that a programmer seeing a `Collection` *expects* the contains method to work based on equals and countering with the fact that yours **doesn't** you're violating the "Principle Of Least Surprise".

This also leads to code handling collections behaving differently depending on what implementation you pass in, which is **never** desirable.

In general I think that relying **solely** on hashCode for contains is a bad idea, even when it's best practice to override hashCode so the resulting hashes of equal objects are equal and those of nonequal objects aren't.

Comment: If you implement `equals()`, you **have also to** implement  `hashCode()` in a consistent way. After all, `HashSet` etc. also use a hash to speed up its `contains()`-method. Of course, it does not mean it is a good idea to override `containsAll()`

Comment: *"relying on hashCode for contains is a bad idea"* - do you really think that `HashMap` is a bad idea???

Comment: @maaartinus no, far from it. But a HashMap doesn't belong to the Collections API (for one) and secondly is quite explicit about relying on hashCode and not equals. A class implementing `Collection` should obey the contract as laid out in the interface. If they use hashCode to assist, they shall, but the formal verification should happen with .equals

Comment: @user140547 I have seen too much code that overrides hashCode differently from equals to see "overriding equals presupposes a consistent hashCode override" actually happening

Comment: You're right, a `HashMap` is no collection. But a `HashSet` is and it's nothing but a simple `HashMap` wrapper. And with a `hashCode` inconsistent with `equals`, it always breaks. There's no way to use "hashCode to assist" only. +++ *"I have seen too much code that overrides hashCode differently from equals"* - what should I say? Deepest sympathy? *Who* writes such crap?

Answer (score 6):

This implementation has a bug. Consider the following code:

```
List<Integer> jdkList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> myList  = new MyArrayList<>();
List<Integer> empty = new ArrayList<>();

System.out.printf("%b\n", jdkList.containsAll(empty));
System.out.printf("%b\n", myList.containsAll(empty));
```

The output is

```
true
false
```

Answer (score 5):

You are hitting a special case for your array as the hash function of `Integer` by default is just the integer value itself. As soon as you start having a non-trivial hash function your containsAll implementation begins to be slower.

See for example the following code which uses strings of 100 characters.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * This class provides a faster {@link #containsAll(java.util.Collection) }
 * method.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6
 * @param <E>
 *            the actual element type.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {

    static String randomString(int length) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            sb.append((char) (Math.random() * 27) + 'a');
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Returns {@code true} if this list contains all elements in {@code coll}
     * and {@code false} otherwise.
     * 
     * @param coll
     *            the collection to check for inclusion in this list.
     * @return {@code true} if this list contains all elements in {@code coll}:
     */
    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> coll) {
        Set<?> set = new HashSet<>(coll);

        for (E element : this) {
            if (set.contains(element)) {
                set.remove(element);

                if (set.isEmpty()) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        int n = 100;
        List<String> jdkList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> myList = new MyArrayList<>();      
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
            jdkList.add(randomString(n));
            myList.add(randomString(n));
        }

        Collection<String> coll = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
            coll.add(randomString(n));
        }

        // Uncomment for failing test.
        // coll.add(-1);

        // Warm-up and let the JIT do its optimization thing.
        boolean r = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            r ^= jdkList.containsAll(coll);
            r ^= myList.containsAll(coll);
        }       
        System.out.println(r + " " + System.currentTimeMillis()); // First print and timing here to load classes.

        long ta = System.currentTimeMillis();
        boolean result = jdkList.containsAll(coll);
        long tb = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long ta1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        result = myList.containsAll(coll);
        long tb1 = System.currentTimeMillis();


        System.out.println("ArrayList.containsAll() in " + (tb - ta) + " ms. "
                + "Result: " + result);

        System.out.println("MyArrayList.containsAll() in " + (tb1 - ta1)
                + " ms. Result: " + result);
    }
}
```

Output on my machine:

> ```
> false 1436092158685
> ArrayList.containsAll() in 15 ms. Result: false
> MyArrayList.containsAll() in 45 ms. Result: false
> ```

Comment: You're actually pretty wrong. The reason for the slowness is not the slow `String#hashCode`. It can't be as it gets computed just once and cached then. The slowness comes from the fact that that `ArrayList#containsAll` exits quickly when the first non-contained string gets found while `MyArrayList#containsAll` wastes time with the `HashMap` creation. +++ Another problem is that OP's method computes something else, namely `coll.containsAll(this)`.

Comment: @maaartinus What you're saying doesn't contradict my post at all. I'm not saying that `String#hashCode` itself is slow. I'm saying that OP's implementation has to calculate the hash code for every object in the argument container. Which is slow where `ArrayList#containsAll` can exit early. What I'm saying is that OP isn't seeing this behavior because the `hashCode` function of `Integer` is trivial.

Answer (score 4):

You idea is good, but you've got it backwards and the implementation is not ideal.

```
@Override
public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> coll) {
    Set<?> set = new HashSet<>(coll);
```

In case of empty or single-element `coll`, it's wasting time, since the original implementation is optimal.

You should also handle the case of `this.size() < new HashSet<>(coll).size()`, as the answer is then trivially `false`.

```
    for (E element : this) {
        if (set.contains(element)) {
            set.remove(element);

            if (set.isEmpty()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

You got it backwards: You're testing `coll.containsAll(this)`.

Also note that the removal is usually more expensive than a test and you should try to avoid it.

---

Actually, you have to convert `this` to a `HashSet`, rather than the other way round. This may get very expensive if your list is huge. It never amortizes if the list is huge and the collection small.

```
/// Find yourself better names!!!
private static final int MAGIC_1 = 10;
private static final int MAGIC_2 = 4;

public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> coll) {
   if (this.size() < MAGIC_1 || coll.size() < MAGIC_2) {
       return super.containsAll(coll);
   }

   return new HashSet<>(this).containsAll(coll);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think if you have a case in which you need an ArrayList which needs a faster `containsAll()` method, it is OK. But still it feels like being a hack. If you used, for example, a `HashSet` instead of an `ArrayList`, the `containsAll()`  method would probably be more like \$\mathcal{O}(m)\$. A `LinkedHashSet` could preverse insertion order. If you need MultiSets, which are available on 3rd-pary libraries, using a `LinkedHashMultiSet`, you could also preserve insertion order. But it still does not provide random access.

So if you need random access and a faster `containsAlls()` and can provide a fast `hashCode()` method, it is certainly an easy method to get that functionality.